# Variable font weight not reflected in Android Studio Design pane

Tags: android, android-studio, variable-fonts

when I want to use **Font with variable font weight** (`wght` tag) - specifically [Public Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Public+Sans) - and the font is registered in XML file like this (with [`fontVariationSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="100"
        android:font="@font/public_sans_variable_font_wght"
        android:fontVariationSettings="'wght' 100" />

        <!-- ... all weights up to 900 -->

</font-family>
```

it looks like the **weight** is not properly reflected in Android Studio **Design** pane for old kind XML layouts and not even for the font XML.
However during application **runtime**, text is properly rendered.

[image: Design left, runtime right]

(Design left, runtime right)

With **Jetpack Compose**, it's consistent - in both, Design (using `@Preview`) and during runtime it's correct.

With **static** fonts (separate `bold`, `regular` files, etc., this was not an issue.)

Is this known issue of Android Studio (I am running on latest stable AS: `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1`), or is something not properly setup in that XML?

Thanks for any help.